# Color console boxes in linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, console, ncurses

So I have noticed that things (for lack of a better word) like this  [image] 
and 
[image] 
are just done in the console using special characters and changing their color.  I know how to accomplish this on windows but how would I go about doing this in linux (I am using ubuntu if that matters)?  Are there any predefined classes out there to help construct these textboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to create simple standard widgets you may try [dialog library](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/), but if you need something more powerful then [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) is your choice.

Comment: Complementing Zuljin's answer, you also have xdialog [http://xdialog.free.fr/] which is for X (duh)

Answer (score 1):

I see you already accepted an answer but I think [Newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29) is exactly what you are looking for.  Follow the link to the website to download.

Comment: Sorry to bump into this. Newt is nice but I guess it lacks documentation.